# C++ - taking input line by line until blank line and saving into an array alters previous elements of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, input

I am writing a program in C++ that reads in input line by line and each line has a pair of 2 n=integers.
Example:

```
1 10
100 200
201 210
```

After reading these number I am trying to store these numbers in a 2-d array. 
The code is this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int pairs[][2] = {};
    string x;
    int index = 0;
    while (getline(cin, x))
    {
        if (x == "")
        {
            break;
        }
        size_t pos = x.find(' ');
        pairs[index][0] = stoi(x.substr(0, pos));
        pairs[index][1] = stoi(x.substr(pos + 1));
        cout << index << ":" << pairs[index][0] << ", " << pairs[index][1] << endl;
        index++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ":" << pairs[i][0] << ", " << pairs[i][1] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I give only 1 line of input it works properly. But when I try to input more than 1 line of input, then it stores the input into the array but somehow the previous element gets altered to some weird numbers {6422236, 3} . 
I am unable to understand why this might be happening. Is it due to wrong usage of `getline()`?

Comment: Arrays don't stretch and grow and shrink automatically, and the compiler needs to know at compile time how may rows it is. When you write `int pairs[][2] = {}` the compiler knows there must be two columns per row, and the `{}` indicates you want one row initialized to 0. If you want more than one row, you'll need to explicitly declare your array to be larger than one row (either by `int pairs[10][2];` or `int pairs[][2] = {{},{},{}};` for example). A more C++ approach is to handle this with a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I see where I wronged it. Please tell me how I should be reading input line by line until a blank line is entered?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` or `std::vector<std::array<2, int>>`. Read each line into a new `std::vector<int>` or `std::array<2,int>`, then `push_back` that into the major `vector`.